# JavaScript is not applying on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code that I have written in JavaScript and the script is referenced on the webpage. When the page loads, a call JavaScript happens and the logic's action should be rendered on the webpage.

Right now the script is firing on the webpage, but the action is not getting rendered on the webpage. However, if I execute the script on page console, changes happen.

```
<script>
function bannerLoad() {
  var delayAddOn = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(".add-ons").hasClass("current")) {
      if ($('.addons-sidebar.clearfix img').length < 1) {
        $(".addons-container :last").append($('<img>', {
          class: 'img-responsive',
          src: 'https://www.abc.in/content/dam/abc/6e-website/banner/target/2018/06/abc.png'
        }));
      }
      clearInterval(delayAddOn);
    }
  }, 100);
};

window.onload = function() {
  bannerLoad();
};
window.onclick = function() {
  bannerLoad();
};
</script>
```

Can anyone check if there is any issue?

Comment: do you have the necessary libraries imported? such as jQuery.?

Comment: Syntactically, there seems nothing wrong with the code. Can you create a fiddle to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Are the DOM elements rendered before you start making changes to them? Where exactly have you placed your script tag? Ideally, have it in the footer section.

Comment: yeah Imesh, jquery reference is present on webpage

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Have you tried the [jQuery ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event?

Comment: any errors in your console when you run this?

Comment: try window.addEventListener("onload", bannerLoad);

Comment: also remove the semicolon ; after the function close brace (above the window.onload call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the script when the page is fully loaded, else the function will be called and can't find the DOM elements.

You should wrap your code inside the ready function:

```
<script>
    //OPEN THE READY FUNCTION
    $(function(){ 
        bannerLoad(); //Call of your function when the page is fully loaded
        $(window).click(bannerLoad);    
    }); 
    //CLOSE THE READY FUNCTION

    function bannerLoad() {
         var delayAddOn = setInterval(function() 
         {
             if($(".add-ons").hasClass("current"))
             {
                if($('.addons-sidebar.clearfix img').length < 1)
                {

                    $(".addons-container :last").append($('<img>',{class:'img-responsive',src:'https://www.abc.in/content/dam/abc/6e-website/banner/target/2018/06/abc.png'}));

                }

                clearInterval(delayAddOn);
             }
        }, 100);                
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function(){` AND `window.onload` ?? Seems a bit overkill

Answer (score 0):

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page , not just the DOM, is ready.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    bannerLoad(); 
    $(window).click(bannerLoad);   
});

function bannerLoad() {
         if($(".add-ons").hasClass("current"))
         {
                if($('.addons-sidebar.clearfix img').length < 1)
                {

                    $(".addons-container :last").append($('<img>',{class:'img-responsive',src:'https://www.abc.in/content/dam/abc/6e-website/banner/target/2018/06/abc.png'}));

                }
                clearInterval(delayAddOn);
             }
        }, 100);                
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script has some little *issues*. I will try to evaluate them.

1. As `bannerLoad` is a `function` you don't need a `;` at the end. Not an issue, just a hint.
2. As told before, `bannerLoad` is a function. So why would you wrap the function again in a function for your events? Just pass the function name directly, like `window.click = bannerLoad;`. Note that there are no bracers at the end, you just pass the name.
3. You function will always create a new `delayAddOn` variable with a new interval. So every time you click, another interval will be started and run in background. If you will do it like this, you need to put the variable on the outside of your function, to keep only one interval running at a time.
4. There is nothing wrong with using `onload` instead of a ready state from jQuery. But this belongs to you page setup and what you do. It would be more safe to rely on a ready state here, as told by others before. Because you already have a function, you could use it directly by `$(bannerLoad);`.

---

```
var delayAddOn;

function bannerLoad() {
    delayAddOn = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('.add-ons').hasClass('current')) {
            if ($('.addons-sidebar.clearfix img').length < 1) {
                $('.addons-container :last').append($('<img>', {
                    class: 'img-responsive',
                    src: 'https://www.abc.in/content/dam/abc/6e-website/banner/target/2018/06/abc.png'
                }));
            }

            clearInterval(delayAddOn);
        }
    }, 100);                
}

$(bannerLoad);
window.onclick = bannerLoad;
```